# How to find out where new rows have been added in a column?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheets and a list that has new rows added constantly, the added cells are being added in different and random rows (7500 rows).

*This is how it's built:*

**Column A:** 7500 rows of words that need to be manipulated (translated)

**Column B:** the new list is the same as 'column A' yet with new added cells,  (B>7500) the cells are not added at the end of the list but in different and random rows within the list.

I need to preform a **very simple** and dynamic check comparing row A and B and 'marking' in Column C where cells have been added, for later manipulation into another column.

As an example you can see how in Column F row 6 a new cell has been added and i'm using column E to test those changes, when false another if checking the row above, but after another cell is added this statement doesn't work ("not found").

[image]

Anyone here has an idea how to use an IF statement for this?
thanks.

Comment: How far have you come yet? Do you have access to some kind of event notifier? Are the columns sorted in some way? Comparing two columns without any of this will result in effort of scale O(n²), since one has to compare every cell in both columns...

Comment: that is exactly what i've been trying to do. In the meantime i've tried to use an IF statement in column C to compate B to A and in  false; create another IF statement that would check the row above, but is definitely THE WRONG way to do it since if 2 consecutive rows have been added, the rest of the list would be screwed.

Comment: can you give a couple of rows example of the data? Can't you use a formula like `match` in column C that checks in column B if that value is already in column A?

Comment: Edited with photo and example.

Comment: @Erez.Matrix I had assumed that you were looking for a formula to show for each cell in column F if that exact text is present in a cell anywhere in column B. As per the other comment, if you are looking for any changes that are happening in column F, then this is more complex and without a notifier of when changes are made I don't know how to approach this. Hope someone else can suggest a solution for you :)